# How to Prove with n vertices it can be guarded with n/4 guards?

Tags: proof-explanation, computational-geometry

Theorem:

Any orthogonal polygon with n vertices can be guarded with at most n/4 guards

This was proven by: Kahn, Klawa and Kleiman in 1982, but I can't find the proof of how they did this on the internet without paying $50 bucks.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Joe O'Rourke seems to have a proof on his [page](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/books/ArtGalleryTheorems/Art_Gallery_Chapter_2.pdf) that is freely available.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know what page?

Comment: ok, use a 4 color graph, makes sense!  Thanks

Comment: In case you missed it, the word "page" was a link in my previous post.